# particle moving along $x= 3y- y^2$ with $\frac{dy}{dt}=3$ find the speed of the particle when it passes through (2,1)

Tags: calculus

particle moving along $x= 3y- y^2$ with $\frac{dy}{dt}=3$ find the speed of the particle when it passes through (2,1). 
I solved this problem by finding that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 3\frac{dy}{dt} -2y\frac{dy}{dt} = 3(3) -2(1)(3) = 3$ so we know that the velocity in the x direction is 3, and the velocity in the y direction is 3, so the speed of the particle should be $\sqrt{3^2+3^2} = 3\sqrt{2}$, but the answer key says that the answer should be $2\sqrt{3}$. I am not sure what the flaw in my logic was. Could someone please help?
Thanks,
nosyarg

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any flaw in your logic.  Blame the answer key.